# How to modify count down timer in javascript code

Tags: javascript, dom, timeout

is there a way to manipulate a count-down timer to change the time of the countdown to zero much faster? here is the code for the:

```
function CalcTimePercent(i, lastpayment, nextpayment, t, p) {

    var time    = nextpayment - t;
    var hour    = parseInt(time / 3600);
    if ( hour < 1 ) hour = 0;
    time = parseInt(time - hour * 3600);
    if ( hour < 10 ) hour = '0'+hour;
 
    var minutes = parseInt(time / 60);
    if ( minutes < 1 ) minutes = 0;
    time = parseInt(time - minutes * 60);
    if ( minutes < 10 ) minutes = '0'+minutes;
    var seconds = time;
    if ( seconds < 10 ) seconds = '0'+seconds;
 
    timer = hour+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    document.getElementById('deptimer'+i).innerHTML = timer;


    
    if(timer == "00:00:00") {
        top.location.href='';
    }

            if(timer == "00:00:0-64") {
        top.location.href='';
    }
    t = t + 1;
    setTimeout("CalcTimePercent("+i+", "+lastpayment+", "+nextpayment+", "+t+", "+p+")",1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is using JavaScript's `Date` class. You would get the time the timer would end, as well as the current time, and constantly check the difference between the two. Here is how you would do that in your case:

```
let timer = null;

function runTimer(time) {
    clearInterval(timer);

    timer = setInterval(() => {
        const timer = new Date(time.getTime() - new Date().getTime()); // Get difference between now and the end time

        const timerText = `${timer.getUTCHours()}h ${timer.getMinutes()}m ${timer.getSeconds()}s`; // Generate a stylised version of the text
        // document.getElementById("ELEMENT_ID").textContent = timerText; // Apply the stylised text to the timer element
        console.log(timerText); // Apply the stylised text to the timer element
    }, 1000); // Run this every 1000ms (1 second)
}

runTimer(new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 60000)); // Start timer for 10 minutes in the future

setTimeout(() => { // Wait 5 seconds
    runTimer(new Date(Date.now() + 15 * 60000)); // Update timer for 15 minutes in the future
}, 5000);
```

The limitation of this method include the fact that it only supports times up to 24 hours. Any time over that will loop back (A timer of 27 hours will show up as "2h 0m 0s").